# Generate random numbers from lognormal distribution in python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I need to generate pseudo-random numbers from a lognormal distribution in Python.  The problem is that I am starting from the **mode** and standard deviation of the *lognormal* distribution.  I don't have the mean or median of the lognormal distribution, nor any of the parameters of the underlying normal distribution.

[`numpy.random.lognormal`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.lognormal.html) takes the mean and standard deviation of the underlying normal distribution.  I tried to calculate these from the parameters I have, but wound up with a quartic function.  It has a solution, but I hope that there is a more straightforward way to do this.

[`scipy.stats.lognorm`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.lognorm.html) takes parameters that I don't understand.  I am not a native English speaker and the documentation doesn't make sense.

Can you help me, please?

Comment: In the docs, you linked, you have: `r = lognorm.rvs(s, size=1000)` where `s` is the shape parameter for the distribution.

Comment: I want to be clear before I do any work on this: you want to generate random numbers with a given **mode** and standard deviation (**not** with a given mean and standard deviation).

Comment: Incidentally, in English "standard" is spelled with a final D, not a final T.

Comment: Yes, Ill edit my question as well. What I know: mode and standard deviation of lognormal distribution. What I need: generate numbers from lognormal distribution with that mode and sd.

Comment: Then the nuisance here is that the scipy.stats version of lognorm is parameterised in terms of the **median** and the standard deviation, rather than the mode. We need a way of expressing the scipy version in terms of the mode and standard deviation. Confusing indeed.

Comment: Do you have only one lognormal distribution to deal with? If so then what are its mode and standard deviation?

Comment: No, I am trying to make sort of random data generator suited for my needs, so I need to set mode and sd every time I generate new data.

Comment: What would *typical* values for mode and standard deviation be? Or ranges of values?

Comment: Not sure If I understand your question. Basically mode should be any real number (in most cases integer) between lets say 1 and 1000. Standard deviation should be any real number within same range.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have the mode and the standard deviation of the log-normal distribution.  To use the `rvs()` method of scipy's `lognorm`, you have to parameterize the distribution in terms of the shape parameter `s`, which is the standard deviation `sigma` of the underlying normal distribution, and the `scale`, which is `exp(mu)`, where `mu` is the mean of the underlying distribution.

You pointed out that making this reparameterization requires solving a quartic polynomial.  For that, we can use the `numpy.poly1d` class.  Instances of that class have a `roots` attribute.

A little algebra shows that `exp(sigma**2)` is the unique positive real root of the polynomial

```
x**4 - x**3 - (stddev/mode)**2 = 0
```

where `stddev` and `mode` are the given standard deviation and mode of the log-normal distribution, and for that solution, the `scale` (i.e. `exp(mu)`) is

```
scale = mode*x
```

Here's a function that converts the mode and standard deviation to the shape and scale:

```
def lognorm_params(mode, stddev):
    """
    Given the mode and std. dev. of the log-normal distribution, this function
    returns the shape and scale parameters for scipy's parameterization of the
    distribution.
    """
    p = np.poly1d([1, -1, 0, 0, -(stddev/mode)**2])
    r = p.roots
    sol = r[(r.imag == 0) & (r.real > 0)].real
    shape = np.sqrt(np.log(sol))
    scale = mode * sol
    return shape, scale
```

For example,

```
In [155]: mode = 123

In [156]: stddev = 99

In [157]: sigma, scale = lognorm_params(mode, stddev)
```

Generate a sample using the computed parameters:

```
In [158]: from scipy.stats import lognorm

In [159]: sample = lognorm.rvs(sigma, 0, scale, size=1000000)
```

Here's the standard deviation of the sample:

```
In [160]: np.std(sample)
Out[160]: 99.12048952171304
```

And here's some matplotlib code to plot a histogram of the sample, with a vertical line drawn at the mode of the distribution from which the sample was drawn:

```
In [176]: tmp = plt.hist(sample, normed=True, bins=1000, alpha=0.6, color='c', ec='c')

In [177]: plt.xlim(0, 600)
Out[177]: (0, 600)

In [178]: plt.axvline(mode)
Out[178]: <matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x12c5a12e8>
```

The histogram:

[image: histogram]

---

If you want to generate the sample using `numpy.random.lognormal()` instead of `scipy.stats.lognorm.rvs()`, you can do this:

```
In [200]: sigma, scale = lognorm_params(mode, stddev)

In [201]: mu = np.log(scale)

In [202]: sample = np.random.lognormal(mu, sigma, size=1000000)

In [203]: np.std(sample)
Out[203]: 99.078297384090902
```

---

I haven't looked into how robust `poly1d`'s `roots` algorithm is, so be sure to test for a wide range of possible input values. Alternatively, you can use a solver from scipy to solve the above polynomial for `x`.  You can bound the solution using:

```
max(sqrt(stddev/mode), 1) <= x <= sqrt(stddev/mode) + 1
```

Comment: Very helpfull indeed. Although computed std as accurate as given one, I thing this is the best solution. But let me ask, is there any way to minimaze the computation error of std?

Comment: @Bobesh That isn't really "error".  I interpreted the question as drawing a sample from a distribution with known *population* mode and standard deviation.  In general, the statistics of the sample will not exactly equal the population statistics. (E.g. if you roll a six-sided die three times, the expected mean value is 3.5, but it would be impossible for the actual mean of the sample to be exactly 3.5.)

Comment: Yes, I see it now. Sorry I misinterpreted the results. thanks again!

Comment: Still one little edit is needed. Desired root of polynomial must be real and greater than one, not than zero. Its because log transformafion of sqrt of that root must be real and greater than zero.

Comment: If `stddev/mode` > 0, that quartic polynomial has two real roots, one negative and one greater than 1, so the test for the real part being greater than 0 should work.  Did you find a case where it didn't?

Answer (score 1):

The [log-normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution) is (confusingly) the result of applying the *exponential* function to a normal distribution.  Wikipedia gives the relationship between the parameters as

[image: mu = log(m/sqrt(1 + v/m^2)), sigma = sqrt(log(1 + v/m^2))]

where *μ* and *σ* are the mean and standard deviation of what you call the "underlying normal distribution", and *m* and *v* are the mean and *variance* of the log-normal distribution.

Now, what you say you have is the **mode** and **standard deviation** of the log-normal distribution.  The variance *v* is just the square of the standard deviation.  Getting from the mode to *m* is trickier:  again quoting that Wikipedia article, if the mean is [image: exp(mu + sigma^2/2)] then the mode is [image: exp(mu - sigma^2)].  From this, and the above, we can deduce that

[image: log m = log n + 3/2 log (1 + v/m^2)]

where *n* is the mode of the log-normal distribution and *v*, *m* are as above.  This reduces to a quartic,

[image: m^8 = n^2m^6 + 3vn^2m^4 + 3n^2v^2m^2 + n^2v^3]

or

[image: u^4 - n^2u^3 - 3vn^2u^2 - 3n^2v^2u - n^2v^3 = 0]

where *u* = *m*<sup>2</sup>.  I suspect this is the same quartic you mentioned in your question.  It can be solved, but like most quartics, the radical form of the solutions are a [giant hairball](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+[log+m+%3D+log+n+%2B+%283%2F2%29*log%281+%2B+v%2F%28m%5E2%29%29]+for+m).  The most practical approach for your purposes might be to plug numeric values for *n* and *v* into the above and then use a *numeric* solver to find the positive root(s).

Sorry I can't be more help.  This is really a math question, not a programming question; you might get more helpful answers on https://math.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Because I dont know mean and standart deviation of that lognormal distribution, but mode and standart deviation of that distribution.

Comment: @Bobesh You said in your question that you know the mean and standard deviation of the lognormal distribution you are trying to sample! Those are *m* and *sqrt(v)* respectively.

Comment: I am confused. Maybe my english is worse than I thougt, but I wrote: My task is very simple: I need to generate pseudo-random numbers from lognormal distribution in python with given mode and standart deviation of that LONGORMAL distribution, not underlying normal distribution.

Comment: @Bobesh I am also confused, but I think I know how to clear things up.  Please answer Bill Bell's comment on your question.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @WarrenWeckesser excellent answer, here's a function that provides the exact return values to reparametrize a lognormal distribution in terms of the mode and the SD:

```
import numpy as np
def lognorm_params(mode, stddev):
    a = stddev**2 / mode**2
    x = 1/4*np.sqrt(-(16*(2/3)**(1/3)*a)/(np.sqrt(3)*np.sqrt(256*a**3+27*a**2)-9*a)**(1/3) +
                    2*(2/3)**(2/3)*(np.sqrt(3)*np.sqrt(256*a**3+27*a**2)-9*a)**(1/3)+1) + \
        1/2*np.sqrt((4*(2/3)**(1/3)*a)/(np.sqrt(3)*np.sqrt(256*a**3+27*a**2)-9*a)**(1/3) -
                    (np.sqrt(3)*np.sqrt(256*a**3+27*a**2)-9*a)**(1/3)/(2**(1/3)*3**(2/3)) +
                    1/(2*np.sqrt(-(16*(2/3)**(1/3)*a)/(np.sqrt(3)*np.sqrt(256*a**3+27*a**2)-9*a)**(1/3) +
                                 2*(2/3)**(2/3)*(np.sqrt(3)*np.sqrt(256*a**3+27*a**2)-9*a)**(1/3)+1))+1/2) + \
        1/4
    shape = np.sqrt(np.log(x))
    scale = mode * x
    return shape, scale
```

Essentially, I just computed the exact solution of the quartic. The advantages are that the solution is a) exact, b) faster and c) vectorizable. As in the case of the answer by @WarrenWeckesser, this function returns, for a given mode and SD, the parameters shape and scale as used by the scipy function scipy.stats.lognormal().